# White Lines above Table Rows in HTML

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get rid of white lines that appear above each row/table in the following HTML. It is just two simple tables, each with a row of icons linking to social networking sites. I have tried applying `style="border:none"` to the `table`, `tr`, and `td` components to no avail, and have tried `border:none` as well.

Please have a look at the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3545rrnz/

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""><img src="facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="instagram.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="pinterest.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="twitter.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="17px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="yelp.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="12px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="tripadvisor.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="12px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="youtube.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post a working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: try box-sizing: border-box; and border-spacing: 0;

Comment: When specifying width as an attribute, don't specify `px` as a unit.

Comment: Why are you using a table?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3545rrnz/. I could see no white-lines perhaps because of the white background. Questions - 1. Are you using any other background other than white? Does your image icons contain white border? In such cases its always recommended to to post whole code using fiddle.

Comment: @adam-west - please your own image icons to http://jsfiddle.net/3545rrnz/ so it becomes much easier to give solution.

Comment: I think tables have their uses @SarahJane although in this case it doesn't look like the right choice for social icons. The only other thing I'd say Adam (in addition to the advice @JoãoVilaça gave) is to remove all white-space between line breaks and don't use the `width` and `height` attributes throughout. Use the `style` attribute and set widths and heights within that.

Comment: It dosen't seems to create any border or white lines [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awuuozjo/)

Comment: Could be a white-space issue (see my comment above) caused in the particular IDE/text editor being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not to use tables for it.

**Much better DIV based solution:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.social-icon {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="social-icons">
    <div class="social-icon facebook"><a href=""><img src="http://www.teamcanada72.com/img%20o/icons/35x35/facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></div>
    <div class="social-icon facebook"><a href=""><img src="http://www.teamcanada72.com/img%20o/icons/35x35/facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></div>
    <div class="social-icon facebook"><a href=""><img src="http://www.teamcanada72.com/img%20o/icons/35x35/facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></div>
    <div class="social-icon facebook"><a href=""><img src="http://www.teamcanada72.com/img%20o/icons/35x35/facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Please visit - http://jsfiddle.net/3545rrnz/5/ for demo. You may add you own icons and manage space around it through PADDING or MARGINE.

Comment: @ Pralhad I used divs like you recommended and created a second `div` for the second row, adding the `clear:left` property to the style. Then I adjusted the padding and widths of the second row for aesthetic purposes. This worked much better than tables, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border:0px;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""><img src="facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="instagram.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="pinterest.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="15px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="twitter.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="17px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="yelp.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="12px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="tripadvisor.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
        <td width="12px"></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="youtube.png" width="35px" height="35px"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the white space in your html and because of the border-collapse property.

Without using a table:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin:0;
}
#iconWrap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#iconWrap img{
  margin: 0 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="iconWrap">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="35px" height="35px">
  </a>
</div>
```

If you really want to use the table for some reason:

```css
table{
  font-size:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="facebook.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="15px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="instagram.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="15px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="pinterest.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="15px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="twitter.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="17px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="yelp.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="12px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="tripadvisor.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="12px"></td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <img src="youtube.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See David Walsh's article [Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) for more info.